How can I test the file upload in Typo3-backend with Testcafe?
I am trying to test a file upload in the Typo3 backend with Testcafe. The problem is that there is no input field with the attribute type=“file”. The file upload is Typo3 standard and initially looks like the screenshot before.jpg.
before.jpg:

If a file is selected manually, the dialog looks like in the screenshot after.jpg.
after.jpg: 
The method setFilesToUpload cannot be used because there is no corresponding input field. There is also no explicit submit button to upload the files.
Alternatively, I have tested the same test case with Playwright. With the FileChooser object it works there without any problems.
My attempts so far:
fixture("Project").page("https://my-project-page");

test("Create data record", async (t) => {
  await t
    // Login
    ...

    .maximizeWindow()

    // File-Upload 
    .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
    
    // Open file upload dialog
    .click(".open-file-upload-dialog")

    // Select files doesn't work
    .setFilesToUpload('???i-have-no-selector-for-this???', [
      './uploads/1.pdf'
    ]))

    // Screenshot
    .takeScreenshot({
      path: "file-upload.jpg",
    })
});

How could this test case in Typo3 be implemented with Testcafe?
